# Field validation as required only if true

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have such a Checkbox and DropDownList with Validator

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIncludeLogin" runat="server" Text='MyCheckBox' Font-Size="9pt"/>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldLanguage" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlLanguage"
   InitialValue="-1" SetFocusOnError="True"  ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="check" 
   Display="Dynamic" Text='*'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I have this problem:

- When I do not check `CheckBox` and do further actions, **Validator** does not start and everything works fine
- When I check `CheckBox` and uncheck it, **Validator** works and does not allow to perform other actions.

How to make the validator not take this field into account when I **check and uncheck** the `CheckBox`?

Comment: Add validation groups that way you can validate an only a specific group of controls on the form.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota Can you provide some good example or link?

Comment: here is an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup?view=netframework-4.8 If you need a working solution from a sandbox, share your entire form code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Since code is tightly coupled and customized very specific to your business needs, I am unable to crack it out.

Comment: Please try add `AutoPostBack = false` in the checkbox and re-test again? Please note, after added it, the backend event of checkbox will not be fired anymore.